# to seek an apology from someone

Tags: phrase-request

If we’ve offended someone and now by making an apology we need to get them to forget it and forgive us. And then be normal to us i.e. no grudge in heart for us. What sentence is the most suitable?

I should please him.

I should  bring him round.

I should make him happy.

I should remove his anger.

Answer (score 1):

The context is not very realistic.  You can't make someone forgive you.

Of the sentences you quote "bring them round" is most idiomatic. You aren't trying to make him happy, or pleased, and "remove anger" isn't idiomatic.

However you begin "I should", so you should focus on what you will do, not what the effect is.

> I should go and apologise, perhaps that will bring him round.

Answer (score 1):

If we’ve offended someone and now by making an apology we need to get them to forget it and forgive us. And then be normal to us i.e. no grudge in heart for us. **What sentence is the most suitable?**

As James comments  **You can't make someone forgive you.** I'll expand on that. You cannot make them Happy and you definitely will not remove their anger by putting the situation onto them when you were the real cause.

The saying is actions speak louder than words and in a case like this that is true. The situation will only be corrected **if** the insulted person see some **sincere and noble actions** from you.Then they may, possibly change their opinion but in there own time.

However what you are suggesting is far from sincere and definitely not noble but self centred and scheming to benefit yourself by adding lies to your list of faults.

**What sentence is the most suitable**? **The the answer is,**

**Butter them up, and tell them what they want to hear and they will come around**,  after all you're just trying to pull the wool over their eyes.